# Can you pass Query Strings to IOS app store and Android play store and use them within the application?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

So to try to explain. I am trying to build something like in-house [Firebase dynamic links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links). Idea is to when an user clicks on a URL, my microservice will redirect him to:

1. Browser if he is on (Windows, Mac, Linux..)
2. App store (on ios devices)
3. Android play store (for android users)

Now in case the user is using a phone I want to redirect him to the app, but would love to pass my query string to the app so that I can later on use to point him to right action within the app. So if the user already has it installed he would just click the open, and if not he would open after installation process. Then I am hoping to use my parameters to redirect within. Hope this makes sense? Anyone knows if this is possible, best solutions?

Keep in mind that the language of this microservice is not super strict, I can use Python, Java, PHP, Go, etc, so any pseudo code works if you want to use it in your answer

Answer (score 0):

Yep this is possible.

You first need to define a link you would like to use with its parameters.

The website the link directs to needs to differentiate between devices based on a user agent probably (there are third party services that already do that.

The website the link directs to needs to also contain an apple-app-site-association file in a specific directory that contains the allowed paths and your app’s bundle id you can check how they’re defined in Apples documentation.

And then in your app itself you can catch the link and parse it however you like, this is called deeplinking and specifically universal libks so you can read up on that.

iOS always prefers to open a universal link inside the app so if the user reached your website through safari then it’s most likely they don’t have the app installed and you can redirect them to the appstore, there’s a way to do it too with universal links.